# How to deploy Angular application on Cloud Foundry using route with path like http://myapp/mycontextpath?

Tags: angular, cloud-foundry, pcf

I'm trying to deploy my Angular (6) application on CloudFoundry.
I want to map my app on a route like http://myapp.domain.com/**mycontextpath** , so **WITH A PATH**.
To do so, I deploy my app (CF PUSH) using a yml file like:

```
---
[...]
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
applications:
- name: myangularapp
  routes:
    - route: myapp.domain.com/mycontextpath
```

In fact, I try multiples things like building my app with or without --base-href parameter like.

```
ng build --prod --stats-json --base-href /mycontextpath/
```

OR

```
ng build --prod --stats-json
```

I always have a 404 not found result.
Everything is working well if I deploy app on a route wihtout path (and without angular --base-href).
I also try to add **Staticfile** file with **pushstate: enabled** content but in that case, my index.html is always returned.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you need a contextpath folder in your final artifact, and the base-href option at build time.
But if you want pushstate, you need some extra steps (see below)

So, the full answer would be :

1) Add base-href option to build command :

```
ng build --prod --base-href /mycontextpath/
```

2) Add an extra folder corresponding to mycontextpath (almost done from Angular 6):

```
{
  [...]
  "projects": {
    "myangularapp": {
      [...]
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          [...]
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/mycontextpath",
  [...]
```

3) Set the route in your manifest file :

```
---
[...]
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
applications:
- name: myangularapp
  routes:
    - route: myapp.domain.com/mycontextpath
```

4) Set your ./Staticfile with :

```
root: dist 
location_include: includes/*.conf
```

5) Create your custom location config in ./nginx/conf/includes/push_state.conf :

```
location /mycontextpath/ {

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /mycontextpath/ break;
    }

    index index.html index.htm Default.htm;

}
```

6) Push dist folder instead of mycontextpath (that's because location_include property requires custom root). Here is the final structure pushed to CF :

```
./Staticfile
./nginx/conf/includes/push_state.conf
./dist/mycontextpath/index.html
./dist/mycontextpath/main-es2015.543563456.js
...
```

7) Regarding static assets, be sure to use paths relative to base-href :

```
<img alt="unicorn" src="./assets/unicorn.png"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact I solve my issue by adding an extra **mycontextpath** root directory to the dist.zip file that I push to Cloud Foundry.

To do so with Angular 6, you can update angular.json file with:

```
{
  [...]
  "projects": {
    "myangularapp": {
      [...]
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          [...]
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/mycontextpath",
  [...]
```

And zip **dist** folder content.